# Why are my MPI-parallelised DO-loops faster the second time round?

Tags: performance, fortran, mpi

I'm working on a scientific model that's parallelised using Open MPI, and I'm finding some weird results with computation time for parallelised loops. Basically, I find that a parallelised loop over a large array is slow right after allocating the (shared) memory, but a second operation is much faster. Why is this?

To demonstrate, here's a dummy program I wrote that illustrates this:

```
PROGRAM test_program
  
  USE mpi
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR, C_F_POINTER
  
  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  INTEGER, PARAMETER                                 :: dp  = KIND(1.0D0) ! Double precision
  
  INTEGER                                            :: process_rank, number_of_processes
  INTEGER                                            :: ierr
  INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)                     :: windowsize
  INTEGER                                            :: disp_unit
  TYPE(C_PTR)                                        :: baseptr 
  REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:,:), POINTER                  :: A
  INTEGER                                            :: win
  INTEGER                                            :: nx, ny, i, j, i1, i2, j1, j2
  REAL(dp)                                           :: tstart, tstop, dt1, dt2
  
  ! Initialise MPI split processes
  CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
  CALL MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_rank, ierr)
  CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, number_of_processes, ierr)
  
  ! Dimensions of data array
  nx = 20000
  ny = 20000
  
  ! Allocate MPI-shared memory for data array, with an associated window object
  ! (done by all processes, but only the master actually allocates any space)
  
  IF (process_rank == 0) THEN
    windowsize  = ny*nx*8_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND
    disp_unit   = ny*8
  ELSE
    windowsize  = 0_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND
    disp_unit   = 1
  END IF
    
  CALL MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED( windowsize, disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, baseptr, win, ierr)
    
  IF (.NOT. process_rank == 0) THEN    
    ! Get the baseptr of the master's memory space.
    CALL MPI_WIN_SHARED_QUERY( win, 0, windowsize, disp_unit, baseptr, ierr)
  END IF
    
  ! Associate the pointer with this memory space (so all processes act on the same physical memory)
  CALL C_F_POINTER(baseptr, A, [ny, nx])
  
  ! Divide the memory over the processors; each gets a range i1-i2 of row
  i1 = MAX(1,  FLOOR(REAL(nx *  process_rank      / number_of_processes)) + 1)
  i2 = MIN(nx, FLOOR(REAL(nx * (process_rank + 1) / number_of_processes)))
  
  ! Do some operations on the data, measure how long this takes on each core
  tstart = MPI_WTIME()
  DO i = i1, i2
  DO j = 1, ny
    A( j,i) = SQRT( (REAL(i,dp) - REAL(nx,dp)/2._dp)**2 + (REAL(j,dp) - REAL(ny,dp)/2._dp)**2 )
  END DO
  END DO
  tstop = MPI_WTIME()
  dt1 = tstop - tstart
  
  WRITE(0,*) '   Process ', process_rank, ': dt1 = ', dt1
  
  ! Do some more calculations on the data, measure how long this takes on each core
  tstart = MPI_WTIME()
  DO i = i1, i2
  DO j = 1, ny
    A( j,i) = SQRT( (REAL(i,dp) - REAL(nx,dp)/4._dp)**2 + (REAL(j,dp) - REAL(ny,dp)/3._dp)**2 )
  END DO
  END DO
  tstop = MPI_WTIME()
  dt2 = tstop - tstart
  
  WRITE(0,*) '   Process ', process_rank, ': dt2 = ', dt2
  
  CALL MPI_FINALIZE( ierr)

END PROGRAM test_program
```

This gives me the following output:

```
    Process            0 : dt1 =    2.1637410982511938
    Process            1 : dt1 =    2.6094086961820722
    Process            0 : dt2 =    1.0437976177781820
    Process            1 : dt2 =   0.96576740033924580
```

Replacing the first loop by a vectorised operation (e.g. `A(:,i1:i2) = 0._dp`) gives the same "fast" results for the second loop.

Comment: what if you do the same thing in a non MPI program?

Answer (score 0):

When you perform memory allocation (such as with `MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED`), the memory is only allocated *virtually* by the operating system: so **until you use it**, it doesn't take up space neither on RAM nor on the disk.

The first iteration writes into the virtually-allocated memory location for the first time, so it causes what is called **page faults**. When handling a page fault, the operating system tries to make the required page accessible at the location in *physical* memory (or terminates the program in cases of an illegal memory access). This process is very **slow**, hence the slow execution.

During the second iteration, no page faults should occur because the memory should be physically mapped, hence the faster execution.

Note that this effect is completely *independent of the use of MPI* (although `MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED` should allocate memory in a different way than usual since memory must be shared between processes).